# Is there a way to use Typhoon DI in tvOS apps?

Tags: tvos, apple-tv, typhoon

In my Podfile i have:

- platform :tvos, '9.0'
- use_frameworks!
- pod 'Typhoon'

and the error i get is:

> [!] The platform of the target `Pods` (tvOS 9.0) is not compatible
>   with `Typhoon (3.4.5)`, which does not support `tvos`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there was pull request recently that adds support for tvOS you can find it in Typhoon version 3.4.7 https://github.com/appsquickly/Typhoon/pull/503